# Enable MFA for external Global Admins AzureAD free

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-security

Trying to enable MFA for all Global Admin accounts in Azure AD.

When navigating in Azure portal to 
`AzureAD->Users->All Users->Multi-Factor Authentication->Global Administrators`,

What I see is a list of all Global Admins, but the checkboxes are all greyed out and clicking a greyed out user shows side pane without `enable` button. Only one that is not greyed out is the subscription user whose email ends with `*.onmicrosoft.com` The others are external invited users.

I think we are using free AzureAD version. (non premium)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-licensing

This docs page says it should be possible to enable it.

Am I missing something or is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to `Azure AD` blade, then to `Security`, then to `Conditional Access`, then select `Baseline policy: Require MFA for admins (Preview)` and enable it

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try to enable this. Documentation is a bit lacking, do you know what happens when this is enabled? Will existing admins be given a number of days to enable MFA?

Comment: I dont think so, they will be required to do so on next login

Comment: Thanks for the help, I enabled the policy and admins were requested to enable MFA on next login. 14 days to skip adding MFA were offered, but did not try if it works.